# Any Nanoseconds difference between the two statements? (return in void)

Tags: performance, return, void

Basically, are there any differences between the two statements in speed (nanoseconds)?

```
private void one() {
   System.out.println("");
}

private void two() {
   System.out.println("");
   return;
}
```

I am very curious about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no difference.

Most compilers would generate the exact same code for both versions, but even if a compiler generated two return statements, of course only the first one would execute.